# How to display category wise posts on seprarate template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single

I have create custom post type and custom taxonomy.

```
/* Custom post type */
function create_post_type() {  
/* models */
register_post_type( 'models',  
    array(  
        'labels' => array(  
            'name' => __( 'Our Models' ),  
            'add_new' => 'Add Model',
            'singular_name' => _x('models', 'models')
        ), 
    'public' => true,  
    'menu_position' => 58,
    'supports'  =>  array('title', 'editor','thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'models'),
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );


/* Custom Taxonomy */
function create_my_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy( 'models_categories', 'models',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'              => 'Our Models',
            'singular_name'     => 'Our Model',
            'search_items'      => 'Search Our Models',
            'all_items'         => 'All Models',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Models',
            'update_item'       => 'Update Model',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Model',
            'new_item_name'     => 'New Model Name',
            'menu_name'         => 'Our Models',
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'sort' => true,
        'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'our-models' ),
        'show_admin_column' => true
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Then i have created a template to display custom taxonomies template name is `archive-models.php` below is the code i am having in this template. And it worked correctly.

```
                <?php foreach (get_terms('models_categories') as $cat) : ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="solutions-we-are-expert-in wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                    <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" class="img-responsive"  />
                    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'models_categories'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, the problem is when i click on any of the category created in this custom taxonomy it should show all the posts published under that category, and then it should go to the post details page respectively.I think i am getting confused in template hierarchy.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `taxonomy-models_categories.php` file in your theme to use as a general template for displaying the posts ('models' in your case) of any selected term ('model category' in your case).

Now, if you wanted to display a different template for a *specific term* you could create a `taxonomy-models_categories-termslug.php` template, replacing 'termslug' with the actual slug of the term.

[wphierarchy.com](http://wphierarchy.com/) offers a great visualization of the WordPress template hierarchy and I often use it as reference. You can also checkout [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) from the WordPress Developer Resources website.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx psymeon,
That solved my problem, i have created taxonomy-`models_categories.php` and now i can see the template.
Do i have to make another template for displaying the details page. I mean like `single.php` for `models_categories` posts.

Comment: You can create a `single-models.php` template to display the details of each post. If you don't create it, your theme's `single.php` template will be used as a fallback. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) might give you some help towards understanding which template is being used in each page. I haven't tried it, but that's what it says it does.

Comment: Great.!
`single-models.php` worked :-)
Thanx a lot buddy, things are now working fine for me.